# How to make a custom checkbox and radio button in pure css?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to make a custom check box and radio button in pure css with cross browser compatible.

I am lookinga result like mentioned below image:-

[image]

I want to this only pure css with ie7

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible using only CSS. But I can be wrong!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have made the css based check box & radio buttons is it near by results ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Vsvg2/78/

Comment: Unless you are the author of the article located at http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css I don't know what to call you Mr Arora!

Comment: @Emin You are very close, but not really on the spot. Look at the images used: background-image: url(https://css-tricks.com/wufoo/themes/customradiosandcheckboxes/radio.png);

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

[**DEMO**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/saohnhik)

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox"> 
  <label class="i-checks">
    <input type="checkbox" value=""> <i></i> Option one
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label class="i-checks">
    <input type="radio" checked="" value="option2" name="a"> <i></i> Option two checked
  </label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.i-checks {
    padding-left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.i-checks input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.i-checks input:checked + i {
    border-color: #23b7e5;
}

.i-checks input:checked + i:before {
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #23b7e5;
}

.i-checks input:checked + span .active {
    display: inherit;
}

.i-checks input[type="radio"] + i, .i-checks input[type="radio"] + i:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.i-checks input[disabled] + i, fieldset[disabled] .i-checks input + i {
    border-color: #dee5e7;
}

.i-checks input[disabled] + i:before, fieldset[disabled] .i-checks input + i:before {
    background-color: #dee5e7;
}

.i-checks > i {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 1px solid #cfdadd;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.i-checks > i:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.i-checks > span {
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.i-checks > span .active {
    display: none;
}
```

OR - follow the this URL: http://fronteed.com/iCheck/